# Short term web hosting

Tags: web-hosting

I have a folder consisting of all my files needed for my website. And this is a website for a school project and I need to share this with my teacher unless I'm live hosting this from visual studio code none of the css or javascript is loading just the basic html. Is there a free Webhosting and domain name I can get to host the website for my teacher temporarily? Or anyway I can share the folder and the teacher is able to view the website the way I see it when live hosting from IDE?

I tried using the google drive web hosting service but apparently that was only possible to 2016, I tried looking up domain names and web hosting services online but they're all paid and I'm not ready to do so.

I hope to able to share my website with my teacher for free and the website can be viewed with all the html, css and javascript.

Comment: https://klawdi.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using codePen you can just copy and paste your code in the online ide you can share with anyone you wish.[CodePen](https://codepen.io)

Comment: Thanks is there anyway to add images to this as well?

Comment: Yes there is an option in settings

Answer (score 1):

If you save all your website files and folders in a public Google Drive folder, then you can use DriveToWeb (https://drv.tw) to access to your website.

Here is a tutorial on Youtube about how to do it:
[DriveToWeb tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pv7iaTaZzIw)

Answer (score 0):

There are many cheap, with monthly plans, hosting solutions such as [Dreamhost](https://www.onlinetoolsexpert.com/dreamhost-web-hosting-review/), [Siteground](https://www.onlinetoolsexpert.com/siteground-web-hosting-review/), [VeeroTech](https://www.onlinetoolsexpert.com/veerotech-web-hosting-review/) and more. Check them out.